# How can I set the speed of manipulate play button?

Tags: dynamic, manipulate

Can you set the speed at which a `Manipulate` plays when the play button is clicked?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`AnimationRate` is at least one way to do this, and it can be applied on a per-control basis:

```
Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 10, AnimationRate -> 1/10, Appearance -> "Open"}]

Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 10, AnimationRate -> 10, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

Comment: I couldn't see this option in the online documentation for Manipulate - although it can be easy to miss things. If it isn't there I think it would be a good addition.

Comment: What is the `Appearance -> "Open"` doing?

Comment: @becko It allows the play button to be visible without needing to first click the '+' next to the slider.

Answer (score 15):

I presume you are looking for `AnimationRate`.
Also, if you want smooth motion you should consider `RefreshRate`.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 5 Pi}],
 {a, 0, 2 Pi, ControlType -> Animator, AnimationRate -> 1, RefreshRate -> 60}
]
```