# Curvature Application

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I found these amazing animations at https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/tam212/avt.xhtml#avt which I think will be wonderfully useful when teaching multivariable calculus next semester. I've started to give Mathematica a try to emulate the first image.

```
d = 4;
r = 3;
l1 = d;
l2 = Pi*r;
l3 = d;
l4 = Pi*r;
totalLength = l1 + l2 + l3 + l4;
positionFunction[t_] := Module[{s, theta},
  s = Mod[t, totalLength];
  Which[
   s < l1,
   {-d/2 + s, 3},
   s < l1 + l2,
   theta = Pi/2 - (s - l1)/r;
   {d/2 + r*Cos[theta], r Sin[theta]},
   s < l1 + l2 + l3,
   {d/2 - (s - (l1 + l2)), -3},
   s < l1 + l2 + l3 + l4,
   theta = 3 Pi/2 - (s - l1 - l2 - l3)/r;
   {-d/2 + r*Cos[theta], r*Sin[theta]}
   ]
  ]
velocityFunction[t_] := Module[{x, theta},
  s = Mod[t, totalLength];
  Which[
   s < l1,
   {r, 0},
   s < l1 + l2,
   theta = Pi/2 - (s - l1)/r;
   r {Sin[theta], -Cos[theta]},
   s < l1 + l2 + l3,
   {-r, 0},
   s < l1 + l2 + l3 + l4,
   theta = 3 Pi/2 - (s - l1 - l2 - l3)/r;
   r {Sin[theta], -Cos[theta]}
   ]
  ]
accelerationFunction[t_] := Module[{x, theta},
  s = Mod[t, totalLength];
  Which[
   s < l1,
   {0, 0},
   s < l1 + l2,
   theta = Pi/2 - (s - l1)/r;
   {-Cos[theta], -Sin[theta]},
   s < l1 + l2 + l3,
   {0, 0},
   s < l1 + l2 + l3 + l4,
   theta = 3 Pi/2 - (s - l1 - l2 - l3)/r;
   {-Cos[theta], -Sin[theta]}
   ]
  ]
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Line[{{-d/2, r}, {d/2, r}}],
   Circle[{d/2, 0}, r, {Pi/2, -Pi/2}],
   Line[{{d/2, -r}, {-d/2, -r}}],
   Circle[{-d/2, 0}, r, {3 Pi/2, Pi/2}],
   {Blue, Thickness[.01], 
    Arrow[{positionFunction[t], 
      positionFunction[t] + velocityFunction[t]}]},
   {Magenta, Thickness[.01], 
    Arrow[{positionFunction[t], 
      positionFunction[t] + accelerationFunction[t]}]},
   Red, PointSize[Large], Point[positionFunction[t]]
   }, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-4, 4}}], {{t, 0.1}, 0, 100}]
```

Which produces this image.

[image]

I have a couple of questions.

1. I know you can slow the animation by clicking the minus icon at the end of the slide bar, then clicking the double down arrow several times until the speed is satisfactory. However, is there something you can put in the code to set the speed?
2. I still haven't been able to draw the bottom part of the first animation on https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/tam212/avt.xhtml#avt and note how it continues to move to the right (without everything jumping around). Don't think I've seen an example of this yet in Mathematica.
3. Finally, if anyone has better advice on how to reproduce this animation, it would surely be appreciated, because I think my students would benefit.

Thanks.

**Add:**

I used this image to understand Nikie's explanation of xTotal=15-x[15]/.sol:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> However, is there something you can put in the code to set the speed?

`Animate` takes an option `AnimationRate`

> I still haven't been able to draw the bottom part of the first animation on https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/tam212/avt.xhtml#avt and note how it continues to move to the right (without everything jumping around).

I think you can get as close as you want by playing with the options to `Plot`, `ParametricPlot` and `Graphics`. For example to prevent the coordinate system from "jumping around", give it an absolute `PlotRange` or combine the dynamic graphics with a static one using `Show` (which will then use the `PlotRange` and other options from the first graphic).

> Finally, if anyone has better advice on how to reproduce this animation, it would surely be appreciated, because I think my students would benefit.

Not sure if it's better, but here's how I would do it:

```
tClothoid = 2/FresnelS[1];
(* define a piecewise linear function for the curvature *)
curvature[t_] := 
 Piecewise[{
    {0, t < 1}, 
    {(t - 1)*4*(Pi/tClothoid^2), t < 1 + tClothoid/2}, 
    {(4*Pi*(1 + tClothoid))/tClothoid^2 - t*4*(Pi/tClothoid^2), t < 1 + tClothoid}, 
    {0, t < 10}, 
    {1, t < 10 + Pi}, 
    {0, True}}]

(* solve the differential equation *)
sol = First@
   NDSolve[{
     x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, γ[0] == 0, 
     x'[t] == Cos[γ[t]], 
     y'[t] == Sin[γ[t]], 
     γ'[t] == curvature[t]}, 
     {x, y, γ}, {t, 0, 20}];

tTotal = 15 - x[15] /. sol;
Animate[
 Module[{tEnd = clock, currentPos, currentTangent, currentCurvature}, 
  currentPos = {x[tEnd], y[tEnd]} /. sol; 
  currentTangent = {x'[tEnd], y'[tEnd]} /. sol; 
  currentCurvature = {x''[tEnd], y''[tEnd]} /. sol; 
  Column[{Show[
     ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tTotal}, 
      ImageSize -> 500, PlotStyle -> Dotted, PlotRangePadding -> .5, 
      Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[currentPos], 
        Arrow[{currentPos, currentPos + currentTangent}], Magenta, 
        If[Norm[currentCurvature] > 10^-5, 
         Arrow[{currentPos, currentPos + currentCurvature}]]}], 
     ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tEnd}, 
      ImageSize -> 500], Axes -> False], 
    Plot[curvature[t], {t, 0, tEnd}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, tTotal}, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> 400, 
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], 
       Point[{tEnd, curvature[tEnd]}]}, Exclusions -> None, 
     AxesLabel -> {"t", "a"}, Ticks -> None]}]], {clock, 10^-5, 
  tTotal}, AnimationRate -> 0.1]
```

[image]

---

**ADD:** (Response to comments)

> Can you point out an article that does a number of examples of the Fundamental Theorem of Plane Curves, Existence?

That's easy: [Modern Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces with Mathematica](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584884487). For example, here's the [section about Clothoids](https://books.google.de/books?id=-LRumtTimYgC&lpg=PA64&vq=clothoid&pg=PA64#v=onepage&q&f=false) and here's the [section about assigning any curvature function to a curve](https://books.google.de/books?id=-LRumtTimYgC&lpg=PA64&vq=clothoid&pg=PA140#v=onepage&q&f=false) (that's what I did above with `NDSolve`).

> The main part I don't understand is how you came up with the curvature function in your opening steps.

I thought the question was about graphics, so I didn't include the derivation for `curvature`. It was a bit tedious, but not hard to understand:

First I want the clothoid to span 180° and I want a closed figure, so `y[t]` at the end of the clothoid should be `2`, because that's the diameter of the circle curve on the left.

To make things as simple as possible for `Solve`, I just looked at the first 90° of the clothoid, where the curvature is simply linear:

```
curvature90[t_] := a*t; 
sol90 = First@
  DSolve[{x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, γ[0] == 0, 
    x'[t] == Cos[γ[t]], 
    y'[t] == Sin[γ[t]], γ'[t] == curvature90[t]}, 
    {x, y, γ}, t]
```

First, solve for the time when the integrated angle `γ` reaches 90°:

```
solT = Solve[{γ[t] == π/2} /. sol90, t]
```

> $\left\{\left\{t\to -\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{\sqrt{a}}\right\},\left\{t\to \frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{\sqrt{a}}\right\}\right\}$

Obviously, I want the second solution, where `t` is positive.

Then I can solve for `a`:

```
solA = Solve[{y[t] == 1} /. Last[solT] /. sol90, a]
```

and arrive at the time the clothoid should take for the first 90°:

```
Last[solT] /. solA
```

> `t -> 1/FresnelS[1]`

so the time for the total 180° clothoid is `tClothoid = 2/FresnelS[1];`

I wanted to be able to play with different values for `tClothoid`, so I solved for `a` separately:

```
Solve[{γ[t] == π/2} /. sol90 /. t -> tClothoid/2, a]
```

> `a -> (4 π)/tClothoid^2`

so that explains the `(t - 1)*4*(Pi/tClothoid^2)` in the piecewise expression.

For the decreasing curvature part, I simply wanted the two piecewise expressions from `t<1+tClothoid/2` and `t<1+tClothoid` to meet at `1+tClothoid/2`, so I solved for:

```
Solve[(t - 1)*4*(Pi/tClothoid^2) == b - t*4*(Pi/tClothoid^2) /. 
  t -> 1 + tClothoid/2, b]
```

and got `b -> (4 π (1 + tClothoid))/tClothoid^2`

So that's how I derived the piecewise function.

In retrospect, it probably would have been much easier to define it as:

```
tClothoid90 = 1/FresnelS[1];
curvature[t_] := 
 UnitTriangle[(t - 4)/tClothoid90]/tClothoid90*π + 
  UnitBox[(t - 10)/π]
```

Finally, I want the figure closed, i.e. I want to repeat the animation at some point of time `tTotal` where `x[tTotal] == x[0] == 0`.

Since this is after the circular arc, `x[t]` is moving at unit speed in the x-direction, so `x[t] == x[t0] + t - t0`, where `t0` is any value after the circle `t0 > 10+Pi`. Solve this for `x[t] == 0` and you get `t -> t0 - x[t0]`. I chose `t0 == 15` for no good reason (I think my original animation ended at t=15) and got

```
tTotal = 15 - x[15] /. sol;
```

(but I could have used `17.9 - x[17.9] /. sol` or `10+Pi - x[10+Pi] /. sol` and have gotten the same value of course)

Comment: This is absolutely magnificent and something I would like to truly understand. The first difficulty is that most books or articles on differential geometry spend a lot of time on proofs of theory but do very few, if any, examples. I've done some searching online, but I haven't been able to find what I need to understand this answer. Can you point out an article that does a number of examples of the Fundamental Theorem of Plane Curves, Existence?

Comment: The main part I don't understand is how you came up with the curvature function in your opening steps. Could you first explain `tClothoid = 2/FresnelS[1];` What does FresnelS[1] return, and why divide 2 by the result?

Comment: My next question would be a needed explanation of `{(t - 1)*4*(Pi/tClothoid^2), t < 1 + tClothoid/2}, `. What does this mean? It obviously gives the left side of the triangle in the lower figure and maybe the first half of the clothed in the upper figure, but why? Very hard for a rookie to understand.

Comment: …and here we see why road designers like clothoids. Nicely done.

Comment: @nikie by chance have you written any books? if you wrote an "image/data processing/analysis in mathematica" book, i'd buy it (as long as it was not more than $85).

Comment: @nikie: Wow! An absolutely incredible explanation. May I ask two more questions. First, t is really s or arc length, correct? Second, how does `tTotal=15-x[15]/.sol` work? I understand the `/.sol` part, but where does the 15 come from?

Comment: @David: Yes, `t` is the arc length. `s` would have probably been a better variable name. I've added a few paragraphs explaining `tTotal` at the end

Comment: @amr: Not yet. I'll think about it ;-)

Comment: @nikie: I added an image to my original post that helped me understand your explanation of `xTotal=15-x[15]/.sol`.

Answer (score 3):

For Question 1:  See the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1349/how-can-i-set-the-speed-of-manipulate-play-button).  The number following `AnimationRate` should be the rate (per second) you want your parameter to increase.

For Question 2:  You can do this via judicious use of `GraphicsGrid`, `Max`, and the `PlotRange` and `AxesOrigin` settings of `Plot`.  If we define `trange` as the amount of time you want visible on your axes, then the following code does the trick:

```
trange = 30;
Manipulate[
 GraphicsGrid[{{Graphics[{Line[{{-d/2, r}, {d/2, r}}], 
      Circle[{d/2, 0}, r, {Pi/2, -Pi/2}], 
      Line[{{d/2, -r}, {-d/2, -r}}], 
      Circle[{-d/2, 0}, r, {3 Pi/2, Pi/2}], {Blue, Thickness[.01], 
       Arrow[{positionFunction[t], 
         positionFunction[t] + velocityFunction[t]}]}, {Magenta, 
       Thickness[.01], 
       Arrow[{positionFunction[t], 
         positionFunction[t] + accelerationFunction[t]}]}, Red, 
      PointSize[Large], Point[positionFunction[t]]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-4, 4}}]}, 
  {Plot[Norm[accelerationFunction[tau]], {tau, Max[0, t - trange], t}, 
         PlotRange -> {{Max[0, t - trange], Max[t, trange]}, {0, 1.1}}, 
         AxesOrigin -> {Max[0, t - trange], 0}, AspectRatio -> 1/3, 
         PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05],
         Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[{t, Norm[accelerationFunction[t]]}]}]}}],
 {{t, 0.1}, 0, 100, AnimationRate -> 1}]
```

[image]

I'm not sure why there are "breaks" in the graph.  Any suggestions for refinement would be welcome.

Comment: `Exclusions -> None` ought to take care of the "breaks".