# AnimationRate not a Manipulate option?

Tags: manipulate, options, version-9

I was trying to set the speed of the Manipulate play button, following [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1349/33913). Namely, I wanted to specify the option **AnimationRate** when I have two or more slider controls.

However, it seems this is not a valid option anymore (I am using version 9), i.e. this does not work:

```
Manipulate[ (*do stuff*) , {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AnimationRate-> value]
```

as `AnimationRate` shows up red. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Your syntax is not as shown in the earlier question.  `AnimationRate` is not an option of `Manipulate` but it is a controller option.  I think you have to specify it twice.

Comment: D'oh, you're absolutely right. I should have specified it within the controller. Thank you very much. This should be an answer.

Comment: You're right, in the end it is just a duplicate; is it ok to delete the question?

Comment: No, don't delete (probably can't because of the upvoted answer).  @Mr.Wizard might be able to link the two questions, if he agrees.  Normally, we vote to mark them as duplicate, but there are more votes to put on hold as a "simple mistake."  It may take the intervention of a moderator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Mr.Wizard, `AnimationRate` is not an option of `Manipulate` but of the particular controller. Namely, the correct syntax is:

```
Manipulate[ (*do stuff*) , {x, 0, 1, AnimationRate-> value}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

If one aims to control the rate of the slider for `x` (analogous code for `y`).